# Is data transferred between oracle server and client secure?

Tags: oracle

My current situation demand connecting one reporting application in London to oracle database in Australia. Direct connection to database was ruled out saying "Security Breach". If SQL Developer in london can connect to database in australia then why application connecting to database is not secure ?

They both are in network and firewall is already opened between these two locations.

Comment: This seems like a question for your security team. It may be a data governance issue; perhaps developers have an exception which is not extended to regular users.

Comment: Security team suggested to transfer data by some other mean. Maybe taking database dump. But end user will have visiblityto of data. Direct access to database was planned by creating another schema and giving only select privilege of all table. So both way data will remain read only. I am trying to understand that is there some serious security issue as security team didn't provided justification.

Answer (score 2):

Oracle controls access by external applications in two ways :

**1. Firewall Access Control**

Oracle Connection Manager can be configured to grant or deny client access to a particular database service or a computer. By specifying filtering rules, you can allow or restrict specific client access to a server, based on the following criteria:

Source host names or IP addresses for clients

Destination host names or IP addresses for servers

Destination database service names

Client use of Oracle Advanced Security

**2. Protocol Access Control**

The database server can be configured with access control parameters in the sqlnet.ora configuration file. These parameters specify whether clients are allowed or denied access based on the protocol.

For more information refer: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/network.101/b10775/intro.htm

Answer (score 2):

IT Security teams don't understand the layers of security in oracle.  There are many different layers under advanced security, such as TDE/securefiles, TNS encryption, authentication such as Kerberos, using dbms_crypto, etc.

Assuming you do NOT use any of the advanced security - then all communication between client, (app server) and database server is in free text, floating around your network. However if this is within a secure firewalled network, then it's a matter of trusting your internal staff not to poke/hack around.  If people are connecting from outside, then you obviously need a secure layer into the application, such as using VPM or secure web components, instead of direct connections to the database.